Felt paper between flooring layers?
Should I install a layer of felt paper between my structural board subfloor (1*6 planks) and the 1/2" plywood underlayment that I'm going to install? Thanks!

What's normally called felt (also known as tarpaper, or roofing felt - black asphalt treated) is not normally used in that role. Red rosin paper used to be.
It's dubious that there's much reason to go buy the stuff with plywood on top, though.

Yeah, I don't think there's much need for anything between the subfloor layers.  A person is going to put an underlay between the actual flooring and the plywood anyway (or it'll be integrated with the flooring).

I've heard some people say it will help reduce squeaking from the floor. Any merit to that?

Also, there are gaps between the floor planks and I'll leave 1/8" gap between my plywood panels... Do I need the felt paper to help keep out cold/hot air?
